# Can you help me with the inference: if ¬( P & ¬Q ) and Q, then P

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, introduction-to-philosophy

I'm taking my classes of symbolic logic, so my question is a bit naïve, but:
If this expression is correct:
¬( P & ¬Q), P then Q.
Why not the following is not:
¬( P & ¬Q), Q then P.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe "valid" and not correct... If so, use truth table.

Comment: If one of the below answers helped you please consider accepting it as well as upvoting. This will avoid extra answers being posted.

Answer (score 2):

> If this expression is correct: ¬( P & ¬Q), P then Q. Why not the following is not: ¬( P & ¬Q), Q then P?

The expression ¬( P & ¬Q) explicitly states that it can **not** be the case that P is the case whilst Q is not the case. So one can derive from this that if P is the case, then Q must be the case, otherwise, you would be inadvertently stating that P could be the case whilst Q is not the case, resulting in a violation of the expression given.

With that understood, the expression "Q then P" simply states that Q **cannot** be the case unless P is the case, but this stipulation does not prevent P from being the case and Q not being the case, allowing a violation of the inital expression ¬( P & ¬Q).

To elucidate, let us provide a real world example. Let us assign the phrase [eating chicken] to the variable P and let us assign the phrase [eating meat] to the variable Q. Given ¬( P & ¬Q), we can translate the statement into:

> "It is not the case that[¬] (one can be eating chicken [P] and not be eating meat [¬Q])."

From there one could easily extrapolate the following:

> "If one is eating chicken, then they are eating meat."

Though one would not be able to extrapolate the following:

> "If one is eating meat, then they are eating chicken"

I hope that helps, please let me know if you have any questions regarding my answer.

-Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 For exemplification.

Answer (score 1):

**R1**. Usually, one is introduced to [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) as `P → Q` in high school geometry because if-then language is so common, and once exposed to truth tables through logic or programming classes, it can be shown that `¬P ∨ Q` is a a rule of inference called [material inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) by truth tables. (The article does it for you.)

**R2**. Now, in high school you were probably also taught that there are four forms of material conditional, the conditional, the [converse](https://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)), the inverse, and the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), and that the conditional and contrapositive are logically equivalent. So it happens to be that `P → Q ≡ ¬Q → ¬P`.

**R3**. You hopefully also recollect [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and know that `¬(P ∧ Q) ≡ ¬P ∨ ¬Q`.

So now you know right away why `¬( P ∧ ¬Q) (P1)` cannot be both `P → Q (P2)` and `Q → P (P3)`. **P1** by De Morgan's Law (**R3**) and then by the material inference (**R1**) becomes the material conditional (**P2**), but the material conditional is not equal to the converse (**P3**), only to the contrapositive by **R3**.

If that English is tough to follow, then the best way is write out the truth tables for P1, P2, and P3.

Comment: Thank you, now I've got it.